# RegEx "replace all but" for Notepad++ v6.3

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

First timer and relatively inexperienced with RegEx and Notepad++. What I am trying to do is replace everything but the policy numbers in these two firewall session. Mind you, I have a list multiple lists 700+ lines long so I want to replace everything in one pass, leaving just the policy number for each line.

```
id 1978781/s23,vsys 0,flag 00200440/4000/0003,policy 4332,time 5972, dip 0 module 0
id 1997645/s23,vsys 0,flag 00200440/4000/0003,policy 30562,time 6283, dip 0 module 0
```

There are thousands of different policy numbers, so a simple search wont do.

I would like my lines to look like this after a replace.

```
4332
30562
```

After two hours of trying to learn RegEx for this one problem, I realized this its more involved than I expected, and I need to spend time learning this since its a very powerful tool. This could really save a lot of time, which unfortunately I don't have at the moment. I'm looking forward to learning more about RegEx and appreciate any help or direction you could give me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the fact the lines always look the same you can use the following

```
^.+policy (\d+).+$
```

Replace by : `$1`

The dot is a wild card so , `.+` means find everything before the word "policy ". Then find a group of digits (`\d+` is for finding digits) and save them (thats what the parenthesis are for in many regex engines). Then find all the characters till the end of the line.

The `^` character means start of line. The `$` means end of line.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

Find:

```
^.*policy ([0-9]+).*$
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

**Why does this work?**

The dot matches any character, and the star means "zero or more of" the character preceding it. This means that `.*` matches *everything*.

What you want is to match everything before and after the policy and erase it, and keep just the policy number, so between your *everything* matchers you look for the string "policy xxxxx" where the xxxxx are numbers.

Each term surrounded by parenthesis in your regex is saved to be used in the replacement. I put parenthesis around the number matcher, `[0-9]+` and then use what was matched in the repace part with `\1`. If your regex contains several parenthesized parts, you can get them with `\1`, `\2`, `\3`...

Regexes are really powerful, you should read a tutorial about them to learn what they can offer.