# Remove all entries except specific words using notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file that contains ID's that I need to retain. The file also contains a lot of other data that I need to remove, however it is not in delimited or fixed width format. So I was wondering if there was a way to use the find/replace function in Notepad++ to remove everything except for the IDs? The  ID numbers themselves start with GO (`GO:000382` for example). I've tried to implement the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884541/regex-replace-all-but-for-notepad-v6-3?rq=1)

without success, however I'm not sure that I'm implementing correctly. I'm using the replace function

```
find = ^.*GO ([0-9] +).*$ and replace =  \1.
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

The data looks like this

```
GO:0043894  :   acetyl-CoA  synthetase  acetyltransferase   activity    [show   def]
Query   matches synonym "Pat    enzyme" [exact  synonym]

molecular   function

8821    gene    products
view    in  tree
GO:0019899  :   enzyme  binding [show   def]    molecular   function

240 gene    products
view    in  tree
GO:0000307  :   cyclin-dependent    protein kinase  holoenzyme  complex [show   def]
Query   matches synonym "CDK    holoenzyme" [exact  synonym]
```

what I'd like back would be

```
GO:0043894
GO:0019899
GO:0000307
```

Comment: Can you please post sample full lines of your txt file ?

Comment: Sure thing. I've amended the question to include the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:[^G]|G(?!O:\d))*(GO:\d+)?
```

Replace with:

```
\1\n
```

[See demo](http://regexr.com?377jj)

I'm adding a line beak between the IDs so they don't appear concatenated. Feel free to use another separator.

Explanation:

- First matches all non-`G` characters or `G` not followed by `O:` and a digit, zero or more times. These will be erased.
- Matches `GO:` followed by 1 or more digits, save the digits into a capturing group.
- The `GO:\d+` group is optional so that this expression easily removes the text after the last match (the first part will match the remaining text).

Comment: That's brilliant thank you. It does seem to delete the GO: at the beginning of each ID. Is there a way to retain these? I'd like GO:0043894 rather than 0043984.

Comment: @user3000124 Oh I was following your OP's example. Updated the answer now. `=]`

Comment: Perfect thank you so much.  The thought of doing this manually was terrifying.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\G.*?(GO:\d+|$)` as global dot-all regex pattern and `$1\n` for replacement.

See demo **[here](http://regexr.com?377k5)**.

Comment: Anyway, is there any reason for the `\G`?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Using `\G` is the best and right way to ensure it will work as wanted. In this case, it would work either without it, which makes pattern even shorter, but I prefer to keep it...

Comment: Ok, I'll trust your word and judgement. It looks like a cleaner solution indeed +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
search:  (?:(\r?\n?|^)(GO:\d{7}).*|(?:\r?\n|^).*)
replace: $1$2
```

Comment: @Ωmega: I have counted.